# Bugged VScode? pandas.concat grays out rest of code

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code

Whenever I use `pd.concat`, the coloring of the code that follows is grayed out, as if it is unreachable (same as if you write code after a return statement in a function)... although it isn't, the script runs normally. Any ideas?

[image: code snapshot]